# C# Excel interop get names all cells of sheet

Tags: c#, excel

On sheet there are some cells that are given names. How to get the names of all the cells in the worksheet, which is given a name.

trying to do so

```
foreach(Excel.Worksheet wSheet in excelPattern.Worksheets)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(wSheet.Name,wSheet.Name);

    foreach(Excel.Name n in wSheet.Names){  
        treeView1.Nodes[wSheet.Name].Nodes.Add( n.Name);
    }
}
```

but do not get what you need

Comment: Have you looked at the [Worksheet.Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.names.aspx) property?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately the result does not match what is on the sheet
     `foreach(Excel.Name n in wSheet.Names){ treeView1.Nodes[wSheet.Name].Nodes.Add( n.Name);`

Comment: There are no exceptions. But I do not see the names of those cells that are actually there on the sheet

Comment: What names are you getting and what names do you expect to get?

Comment: on sheet

`выр_проц; выр_раб_усл; выр_реал_соб`

i get `РОД10!_FilterDatabase;  РОД10!Z_7C371303_C1FE_49B4_A9DD_C1D8D4863FB7_.wvu.Rows; РОД10    РОД10!Print_Area`

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the problem correctly
I needed `workbook.Names` and I was looking for a `worksheet.Names`
  cells names are not attached to the sheet, it is the global cell names

You can get it

```
// var workbook = ...;
foreach(var n in workbook.Names) {
    string name = n.Name;     //  Name of cell 
    string ref  = n.RefersTo; //  Refers To cell (Sheet1!$E$29)
    // ...
}
```